# Cannot convert string to date type

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

My Controller method

```
@GetMapping("/fetch/{one_date}/{two_date}")
    public List<CourierInfo> getData_between(@PathVariable(value = "one_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") Date fromDate, @PathVariable(value = "two_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") Date toDate) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(fromDate);
        System.out.println(toDate);
        String date1 = "20-01-2020";
        String date2 = "24-01-2020";
        Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date1);
        Date d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date2);
        return bookRepository.getData_between(d1, d2);
    }
```

My url I am passing date in

```
http://localhost:8080/book_api/fetch/20-01-2020/24-01-2020
```

I am getting this error

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '20-01-2020'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [20-01-2020]

How can I solve this error. I have tried my different things.

Comment: `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")` and then you pass a date without time

Comment: You pass a date with format `dd-MM-yyyy` but you're trying to parse it as `dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change DateTimeFormat for

```
@PathVariable(value = "one_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

to

```
@PathVariable(value = "one_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

You are only inputing a date, but you instructed the formatter to format time as well.